# NavigationMixin for standard_recordrelationshipPage using a listview developername

Tags: lightning-web-components, relationships, custom, campaign-member, navigationmixin.navigate

Question:
is there a way to use a developer name of listview in a standard_recordrelationshipPage?

In Account object I created a custom single related list in LWC called Active Campaign Related List.

This is my code when clicking view all in footer to navigate to the all active campaign:

```
handleViewAll{
  this[NavigationMixin.Navigate] ({
      type: 'standard__recordRelationshipPage', 
      attributes: {
         recordId: this.recordId, 
         objectApiName: 'Account', 
         relationshipApiName: 'CampaignMember', 
         actionName: 'view' 
      } 
  });
}
```

output: (keeps on going to campaign history it should be all active campaign only) and i have a list view (developername: AllActiveCampaign )
[image]

Is there a way to call this listview developername?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list view and related list are two different things. You cannot customize the related list to show a list view based on record id out of the box inside salesforce.

For example:- On an account record, the contact related list will show all the contacts associated with it. You can not show a list view on the related list.

Coming to [standard__recordRelationshipPage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_page_reference_type) pagereference type, it has just four attributes:-

1. actionName- The action name to invoke. Only view is
   supported.
2. objectApiName- The API name of the object that defines the relationship. Optional for lookups.
3. recordId- The 18 character record ID of the record that defines the relationship.
4. relationshipApiName- The API name of the object’s relationship field.

> Currently, you have to rely on custom component as permanent filter is
> not available for related list.

Comment: oww i see, thank you very much. actually I used navigation mixin  on view all button. But thank you so much I guess it is not possible

Comment: @salesforce_newbie You can accept the answer if it had solved your doubt.